# Error compiling pcl_ros on Debian

Tags: pcl, debian, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I get an error (or lets say a huge error message) when i try to compile pcl_ros on my Debian:sqeezy.

The first error is:
error: ‘__s_getMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘pcl::PointIndices’

I installed the PCL Library with the instructions given at http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html for Debian as distro.

But at the moment, I'm not sure where to look for the problem and how to solve it.

Please give me some tips...

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45125/error-compiling-pcl_ros-on-debian/) by [mwildbolz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3311/mwildbolz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before a compiling pcl, the FLANN package needs to be installed from sources via

```
git clone https://github.com/wg-debs/flann.git
make & make install
```

To install PCL, the solution was to explicitely take the sources from the wg-debs archive via cloning the GIT repository

```
 git clone https://github.com/wg-debs/pcl.git
```

To get the package working, i had to switch some build parts on or off with the command

```
cmake ../ -DUSE_ROS=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_global_tests=OFF
          -DBUILD_examples=OFF -DBUILD_visualization=ON
```

before calling

```
make -j8 & make install
```

I also added the libraries libgtest-dev and libvtk5-dev to the yaml File i created (for the dependencies).

---

Originally posted by [mwildbolz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3311/mwildbolz/) with karma: 26 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1